# How to drop a unique constraint from table column?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, unique-constraint, non-clustered-index

I have a table 'users' with 'login' column defined as:

```
[login] VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
```

Now I want to remove this unique constraint/index using SQL script. I found its name **UQ_*users*_7D78A4E7** in my local database but I suppose it has a different name on another database.

What is the best way to drop this unique constraint? Or at least any...

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430456/how-to-drop-sql-default-constraint-without-knowing-its-name

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I found my unique constraint in sys.indexes table but I have not found any links to table which contains this index. Any help?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I have found a link to my table - it is object_id, but I cannot find a link to necessary column...

Comment: I think it is not possible in full SQL (but OK in script as proposed by @Rail). The best way is to copy the column to a new one, to set your constraints in the new column, to destroy the old one and then to rename the new column with the old column name.

Comment: For Sql server 2014 drop unique key check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041792/11827756

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SKINDER, your code does not use column name. Correct script is:

```
declare @table_name nvarchar(256)  
declare @col_name nvarchar(256)  
declare @Command  nvarchar(1000)  

set @table_name = N'users'
set @col_name = N'login'

select @Command = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table_name + ' drop constraint ' + d.name
    from sys.tables t 
    join sys.indexes d on d.object_id = t.object_id  and d.type=2 and d.is_unique=1
    join sys.index_columns ic on d.index_id=ic.index_id and ic.object_id=t.object_id
    join sys.columns c on ic.column_id = c.column_id  and c.object_id=t.object_id
    where t.name = @table_name and c.name=@col_name

print @Command

--execute (@Command)
```

Comment: This would be broken if there's more than one unique constraint on the column.  Unique constraints can span more than one column, and it's possible for a single column to be part of more than one unique constraint.

Comment: does not works on sql server, it keeps saying that my constraint is not a constraint

Comment: This is the script updated for SQL Server 2017: https://pastebin.com/FerWr612

Answer (score 40):

```
ALTER TABLE users
DROP CONSTRAINT 'constraints_name'
```

if earlier constraints_name is not provided, it will have some default constraint_name, in pgAdmin 4 (pSql), try violating the constraint and you can see the constraint_name being violated in the error received, most probably same must be the case with other platforms or there are some articles available over web where constraint_name is extracted from certain tables where they are stored, not sure about this though.
P.S : Can take reference from comments also

Comment: )) yes, 'constraints_name'... but WHAT IS THIS CONSTRAINT NAME?!

Comment: the constraint name is random. If you want it to be fixed you need to assign it a name on creation. `CREATE TABLE users(login varchar(50) constraint uq_users_login UNIQUE)`

Comment: @Filip De Vos: this table has already been created. And now I cannot remove this index using script. Is there any solution except copying data into a new table without constraint and removing old table (it is rather difficult because I have foreign keys that link to another column in this table)?

Comment: I had to remove the single quotes as in:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] DROP CONSTRAINT [AccountsCardNumberUnique]

But SO came through as always.

Comment: As @Mike said.. No single quotes.

Comment: You can find the constraint name with this query :

Comment: use `sp_help 'table name'` to find out the constraint present in the that table

Comment: does not works on sql server, it keeps saying that my constraint is not a constraint

Comment: To find the constrain name, you can do: `SHOW CREATE TABLE {table-name}`

Answer (score 10):

This works mostly.

```
drop index IX_dbo_YourTableName__YourColumnName on dbo.YourTableName
GO
```

Comment: In SSMS 17, this is what "Drop index Xyz" generates through SMO on a SQL Server 2016 instance.

Answer (score 9):

To drop a UNIQUE constraint, you don’t need the name of the constraint, just the
list of columns that are included in the constraint.

The syntax would be:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP UNIQUE (column1, column2, . . . )
```

Comment: The question is tagged SQL-Server not MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following script :

```
Declare @Cons_Name NVARCHAR(100)
Declare @Str NVARCHAR(500)

SELECT @Cons_Name=name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type='UQ' AND OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = N'TableName';

---- Delete the unique constraint.
SET @Str='ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @Cons_Name;
Exec (@Str)
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this SQL command to drop a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
DROP INDEX column_name
```

Comment: Msg 1018, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.

Comment: Error Executing Database Query. 'column_name' is not a constraint.

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan that `column_name` should be replaced by your column name

Comment: haha @beginner i am not a beginner.. don't know why the error came.. i created duplicate table and changed it.. thank you..

Answer (score 2):

This statement works for me

```
  ALTER TABLE table_name DROP UNIQUE (column_name);
```

Comment: Invalid syntax.

Comment: This worked, and the syntax is even portable between some databases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have stopped on the script like below (as I have only **one** non-clustered unique index in this table):

```
declare @table_name nvarchar(256)  
declare @col_name nvarchar(256)  
declare @Command  nvarchar(1000)  

set @table_name = N'users'
set @col_name = N'login'

select @Command = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table_name + ' drop constraint ' + d.name
    from sys.tables t join sys.indexes d on d.object_id = t.object_id  
    where t.name = @table_name and d.type=2 and d.is_unique=1

--print @Command

execute (@Command)
```

Has anyone comments if this solution is acceptable? Any pros and cons?

Thanks.

Comment: If it works then it's a good script :) don't labour over the problem if this has solved your problem. It's not as though you will be executing a script like this every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Expand to database name >> expand to table >> expand to keys >> copy the name of key then execute the below command:

```
ALTER TABLE Test DROP UQ__test__3213E83EB607700F;
```

Here **UQ__test__3213E83EB607700F** is the name of unique key which was created on a particular column on test table.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to refer a previous question, Because I have faced same problem and solved by this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430456/how-to-drop-sql-default-constraint-without-knowing-its-name).
First of all a constraint is always built with a `Hash` value in it's name. So problem is this `HASH` is varies in different Machine or Database. For example `DF__Companies__IsGlo__6AB17FE4` here `6AB17FE4` is the hash value(8 bit). So I am referring a single script which will be fruitful to all

```
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)
     declare @table_name nvarchar(256)
     declare @col_name nvarchar(256)
     set @table_name = N'ProcedureAlerts'
     set @col_name = N'EmailSent'

     select @Command ='Alter Table dbo.ProcedureAlerts Drop Constraint [' + ( select d.name
     from 
         sys.tables t
         join sys.default_constraints d on d.parent_object_id = t.object_id
         join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
                               and c.column_id = d.parent_column_id
     where 
         t.name = @table_name
         and c.name = @col_name) + ']'

    --print @Command
    exec sp_executesql @Command
```

It will drop your default constraint. However if you want to create it again you can simply try this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProcedureAlerts] ADD DEFAULT((0)) FOR [EmailSent]
```

Finally, just simply run a `DROP` command to drop the column.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm using DB2. What I have done is a bit not too professional solution, but it works in every DBMS:

1. Add a column with the same definition without the unique contraint.
2. Copy the values from the original column to the new
3. Drop the original column (so DBMS will remove the constraint as well no matter what its name was)
4. And finally rename the new one to the original
5. And a reorg at the end (only in DB2)

```
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD COLUMN LOGIN_OLD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
UPDATE USERS SET LOGIN_OLD=LOGIN;
ALTER TABLE USERS DROP COLUMN LOGIN;
ALTER TABLE USERS RENAME COLUMN LOGIN_OLD TO LOGIN;

CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE USERS');
```

The syntax of the ALTER commands may be different in other DBMS

Answer (score 0):

FOR SQL to drop a constraint

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] DROP CONSTRAINT [unique key created by sql]
GO

alternatively:
go to the keys -- right click on unique key and click on drop constraint in new sql editor window.
The program writes the code for you.

Hope this helps.
Avanish.

Answer (score 0):

To find all system generated unique constraint names and other information related to it on any database.

You may use below query and enhance it as per your need:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%UQ%'
```

Final query to drop all unique constraint through database. You may add where clause to restrict it to one table:

```
    DECLARE @uqQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @uqQuery = SUBSTRING( (SELECT '; ' + 'ALTER TABLE [' + Table_Schema+'].['+Table_Name
        +']  DROP CONSTRAINT ['+CONSTRAINT_NAME+']'

    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE '%UQ%'
    FOR XML PATH('')), 2,  2000000)
    SELECT @uqQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.table
DROP CONSTRAINT uq_testConstrain
```

constraint name `uq_testConstrain` can be found under database->table->keys folder

Answer (score 0):

for MSSQL use following codde

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' and COLUMN_NAME = 'colName')
BEGIN 
Declare @con varchar(50);
Declare @sqlStatement varchar(500);

select @con = CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' and COLUMN_NAME = 'colName'
SET @sqlStatement = 'ALTER TABLE tableName DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @con;
    
EXECUTE (@sqlStatement)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sql server 2014 you can remove unique key using below query

First find unique key name using

> EXEC sys.sp_helpindex @objname = N't_Party'

```
DROP INDEX [KEY_NAME] ON [dbo].[TABLE_NAME]

--In my case there ys t_Party table name and 'IX_t_Party' this is unique key name

DROP INDEX [IX_t_Party] ON [dbo].[t_Party]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the name of your constraint then you can directly use the command like

**alter table users drop constraint constraint_name;**

If you don't know the constraint name, you can get the constraint by using this command

**select constraint_name,constraint_type 
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'YOUR TABLE NAME';**

Comment: Not compatible with T-SQL/MS SqlServer