# Deleting a constraint that has not been named?

Tags: constraints

I know how to delete  a constraint but what about deleting a constraint that has not been named.

Here I have used a Check constraint without name.

Example:

```
create table customers
(
 id int not null,
  name varchar(50) not null,
  age int not null check (age>=18),
  [Address] char(50),
  salary decimal(18,2),  
   primary key (id)
    );
```

I tried using following command

```
 alter table customers drop check (age)
```

But, it gives incorrect syntax error.

Is there a simple way to drop a constraint that is not name?

Answer (score 0):

i found someone who have the same problem and solved it !

Take a look here :>

[How to drop SQL default constraint without knowing its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430456/how-to-drop-sql-default-constraint-without-knowing-its-name)